# Open a CRM Entity from a Web Resource

Tags: scripting, cross-browser, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a Web Resource that is working fine, except for one major headache.

I need to be able to click on a link and open an existing entity record. These two methods both almost get me there, but are blocked by different reasons:

**1.** Calling it directly with a link like this:

```
window.open('http://OurCRM/main.aspx?etc=10088&id=%7bc1d0db62-aa9e-e911-80e0-0a94ef08472f%7d&pagetype=entityrecord', '_self');
```

The problem with this one is that it doesn't work due to CRM saying

*"Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Service Xrm.Interfaces.Services.IMostRecentlyViewedService already has an implementation"*

note : If I take out the '_self' it works but then that defeats the purpose of what we're trying to do (need to keep it in the same tab).

**2.** using the Client API:

```
parent.Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm('ourentity', guid, '', '');
```

This one is blocked due to Cross Origin Frames being blocked by browsers.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can accept your own answer & close the thread. Btw, you can upvote the other answers if it helped you..

Comment: Close this thread also - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59572835/7920473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help others out, this was resolved in another, similar question

[accessing the logged in CRM user from custom page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59572835/accessing-the-logged-in-crm-user-from-custom-page/59573099?noredirect=1#comment105313748_59573099)

Basically we were looking at two different ways to handle the same problem of working with webforms inside CRM.

Answer (score 1):

Below snippet should work: (this will be `onclick` of button or link)

```
onclick="window.location.href='http://OurCRM/main.aspx?etc=10088&id=%7bc1d0db62-aa9e-e911-80e0-0a94ef08472f%7d&pagetype=entityrecord';"
```

Comment: :-( ... got this again:
"Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Service Xrm.Interfaces.Services.IMostRecentlyViewedService already has an implementation"

Comment: @RodneyEllis I never faced this. Which CRM version you are using? Online?

Comment: Microsoft Dynamics® CRM 2016
(8.0.0.1088) (DB 8.0.0.1088)
Thank you for help.

Comment: @RodneyEllis: https://github.com/MscrmTools/XrmToolBox/issues/151 says invalid crm Org url is culprit. The url works directly in browser? Also verify any Sitemap or ribbon has this same url hardcoded issue

Comment: Yes, when I copy/paste the URL in the browser it's fine. Only when calling it from the code I get the error. I just had a read of that article but I'm more confused now than before. This is the Url on the sitemap editor:  http://ausyddev01/crm/Pages/Events/EventRequests.aspx  - on this event requests webform we have some asp objects populated from CRM and then the button where we want to redirect to the crm entity. all works, except this last button.