# accessing the logged in CRM user from custom page

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We have Dynamics CRM and a webform which is loaded from the ribbon, essentially inside an iframe.

How do we get the logged on user? On the top right, is my name and image as logged in via Active Directory. However, if I do something like:

```
var UserID = window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
```

or in C#:

```
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current; 
lblUser.Text = user.SamAccountName;
```

then we get the generic user that CRM is configured to use.

If I do a right click on the entire form and go "View Source",  I can see this:

```
var USER_NAME = 'Rodney Ellis';
```

In Chrome's developer tools I can run this from the Console, and my name appears:

```
alert(USER_NAME);
```

But when I try to access it from javascript in the code it says it can't be found:
*Uncaught ReferenceError: USER_NAME is not defined*

How can I get the Username from inside the aspx webform, either by c# or js? Cross-side scripting being blocked has stopped a lot of the easy ways, hence why we're looking for a work-around.

Comment: Which version of the Dynamics CRM you are using? The answer depends on it.

Comment: Microsoft Dynamics® CRM 2016 (8.0.0.1088) (DB 8.0.0.1088)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of the all time great hacks ... we got around the problem by embedding another iFrame into a web resource!

So the web resource can call Xrm.Page.context.getUserName() and then concatenate that to the querystring which we then pass into an iFrame. because CRM thinks the iframe is just one control, it allows all the webform commands taking place inside of it and doesn't give any 500 errors.

Answer (score 1):

The below code should give you what you want. [Read more](https://neilparkhurst.com/2016/08/03/crm2016-javascript-context-object/)

```
Xrm.Page.context.getUserName();
```

But based on popup or inline embedded iframe, you have append in front.

```
window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getUserName();
window.opener.Xrm.Page.context.getUserName();
```

Comment: already tried that ... i get this:   "Blocked a frame with origin "" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Comment: @RodneyEllis then you should get that value and pass it as query string to custom page iframe url while opening from ribbon.

Comment: i've spent all day trying to doing that, but then whenever i do a postback i get the famous 500 Page error. the userid comes across in the first load but any call to the c# code which causes a postback and it fails.

Comment: @RodneyEllis I believe you are hosting a separate .net app & using it inside CRM (instead of web resource) - so get the query string & store it in cookie or session variable from first load for further usage after post back.

Comment: " believe you are hosting a separate .net app & using it inside CRM" - correct. I was playing with session variables but couldn't figure out how to set it in the web resource and gave up as i wasn't sure it would work or not. i'll go back and try and figure out how to do that. thank you